# Superman's Morality: Has the idea that his morals are in a sense also super been discussed?

Tags: dc, comics, superman, morality

Throughout the years, Superman has been sorely tested by some very bad humans and aliens but afaik, the number of times he had taken life has been very few and there has always been an extraordinary reason. His vow not to take life has been observed I would argue with much more faithfulness than any mortal human. Is it suggested that he is in fact constrained more by his vow than a human is even capable of being constrained?

Comment: With super power comes super responsibility?

Comment: I won't say he has "super morals" per se. Perhaps, more accurately, is his mind possessing a super-enhanced ability to maintain its resolve, determination and resistance to swaying from its path and succumbing to temptation. If he has physical super-strength, why not mental?

Comment: @thegreatjedi: That is my thinking -- this is not some normal human vow; but I wonder if it has been discussed in any movie or comic book/graphic novel?

Comment: I can understand your question, but it is not that far of a stretch. I can think of MLK, Mother Teresa, and Corporal Doss off the top of my head as 3 individuals that did not condone violence. That is even more extreme than not taking a life in most cases. And as you mentioned, he has taken life. He does his damnedest not to, but when push comes to shove, he has the resolve to do what is necessary.

Comment: @odin1806 I think we see in many of those weaknesses of character that Superman lacked.

Comment: I vaguely recall an episode of Justice League or JLU, not comic canon I know but possibly relevant. Superman was fighting Darkseid and commented that he didn't have to hold back in that fight. I feel like, possibly due to his Kansas upbringing, Clark has spent most of his life trying not to hurt people-even accidentally-so killing is almost out of the question.

Comment: @Jeff If i understand your comment correctly; Character and morals go hand in hand. Superman didn't really lack character or morals, he just walked a very thin line, which I would say is even more difficult. I can either swear off violence or condone it, and from then on, you know exactly what I will do or feel or think about a situation. Walking the line and choosing what side to be on in a situation is more difficult. And you do not have to like "the right decision" when you make it. Life is not black and white IMO and walking that line is much more honest and true.

Comment: Not canon, but... http://www.smbc-comics.com/?id=3637

Comment: If they haven't then shame on them, it's by far the most important aspect of the character. The modern Messiah.

Answer (score 7):

A lot has been tossed about in this regard. Superman/Wonder Woman #3 kind of explored this in a modern context, where Diana Prince/Wonder Woman and Superman kinda have a *thing* going. And so, of course, who better to discuss this with than the socially well adjusted Batman

[image]

Superman's morality, for the most part, comes from a strong upbringing by the Kents. Their simple morals seeped into their adopted son and they turned him into a fine man. Who happens to be able to punch the moon into dust.

It's that last part that probably plays into the "don't kill" philosophy. Man of Steel (the movie) really delved into what happens when Superman isn't so concerned with saving innocent lives. Humans became collateral damage. While there are times you can't avoid that, Superman there doesn't seem to think that's priority #1 but maybe #2 or #3 ([the order of rules is kinda important](https://xkcd.com/1613/)). Man of Steel wrecks a lot of stuff willy-nilly.

Modern Superman puts "Don't kill" at #1. Because, unlike Batman, if Superman gets it wrong you could be facing a holocaust really quick. Knowing you have a god-like being who has vowed not to harm you puts a lot of people at ease.

Comment: My point is, he would not get it from the Kents who are merely human. Did they oppose WW2? Were they Quakers? And if so, I assert he has superhuman morality.

Comment: @Jeff Why can't the Kent's morality be superhuman? If you are the strongest man on Earth, you become an athlete. If you are the smartest, a professor or inventor. If you are the most morally upright....then what? Farmer in Kansas seems as suitable a job as any in that case.

Comment: @kingledion: Why can't the Kents' be superhuman? Because they are human. They might be exceptional among humans in their morality but not at the level than a Kryptonion can be. If my theory is correct.